# Define new macro "defn", lein uberjar succeeds, lein run fails to compile

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I defined my own defn in the namespace mwm.

My new code looks like this

```
(mwm/defn foo [x] ...)
```

Everything was fine as long as it was called defn2, but after renaming it to defn and refering to the original defn using clojure.core/defn, only "lein uberjar" works.

When I run "lein run", the compilation fails as

```
c:\data3\clojure\cdn77-purge>lein run
WARNING: defn already refers to: #'clojure.core/defn in namespace: mw.mwm, being
 replaced by: #'mw.mwm/defn
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mw.mw1, compiling:(
mw/mw1.clj:40:1)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6543)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6485)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3791)
        at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6725)
```

The code can be found at https://github.com/mattiasw2/cdn77-purge/tree/renamed_to_defn

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [`:refer-clojure`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/refer-clojure) clause in your `mw.mwm` namespace:

```
(ns mw.mwm
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [defn])
  (:require
    [clojure.pprint :as pp]
    [clojure.walk :as walk])
  (:gen-class))
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work. Somehow, I need to make sure lein generates the class mw.mwm before it compiles the other files.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my own definition of defn to a separate project, so it seems you cannot redefine defn within the same project it is used.